# Почему возникает ошибка с базой данных в докере?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Подскажите пожалуйста почему возникает ошибка и как её исправить?Заранее благодарен

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is
> improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings
> documentation for more details.

.env

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=key
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
DB_NAME=name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASS=username
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```